# Is there a specific example of using JavaScript for an Attachment via the Evernote API?

Tags: javascript, evernote

I'm looking to do an Attachment via the Evernote API.

The web page here:

https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/creating_notes.php#

Has a section for creating attachments, but the two code samples are incorrect (they are createNote samples) and they are only Python and Objective-C.

Is there an example of how to use the Evernote JavaScript API for an attachment?

Comment: Javascript on the server side, right? Does the Node.js example on that page help?

Comment: Yes, the last example helps. It appears what is missing is the sample code for the middle part:

Here’s a simple function for turning a collection of files into Resource instances suitable for adding to an Evernote note:

And then that sample has nothing to do with Resources. I can't find a way to report a bug in their developer docs to Evernote.

And no, this is client side.

Comment: Incidentally, here's the code that's supposed to be linked in that section:
https://gist.github.com/evernotegists/5313823
I want a node.js version of that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example code creating a note containing only a png file:

```
import {Evernote} from 'evernote';
import md5 from 'md5'

// I have a base64 encoded file, convert to Buffer
const binaryResource = new Buffer(fileData, 'base64');
const fileMime = 'img/png'; // or whatever your mime type is
const fileName = 'testImage.png'; // or whatever your mime type is
const md5Hash = md5(binaryResource);
const resourceAttributes = new Evernote.ResourceAttributes({
  fileName: fileName,
});
const resource = new Evernote.Resource({
  data: new Evernote.Data({body: binaryResource}),
  mime: fileMime,
  attributes: resourceAttributes,
});
const content = ''
  + '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
  + '<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">'
  + '<en-note>'
  + '  <en-media type="' + fileMime + '" hash="' + md5Hash + '"/>'
  + '</en-note>';
const n = new Evernote.Note({
  title: fileName,
  content: content,
  resources: [resource],
});
const evernoteClient = new Evernote.Client({
  token: authToken,
  sandbox: false, // true for sandbox testing
});
evernoteClient.getNoteStore().createNote(n, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error creating note: ' + err);
  } else {
    console.log('Created note: ', res);
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the Buffer datatype? That's not a JS datatype and I don't see it in the Evernote code.

That's my confusion here. What exactly should the data look like? An ArrayBuffer?

I did get a text/plain attachment working, but it doesn't look like evernote honored the filename in resource attributes...